# В чем причина ошибок?

Tags: php

По  [этой](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=350)  ссылке учился делать регистрацию, но в 5 пункте (изменение файла index) заметил появление 4-х ошибок 36, 84, 89, 90 строчки, пробовал исправить сам - ничего не получается, помогите исправить или скажите, что я делаю не так!

Код невозможно привести! (почему-то когда вставляю весь код вопрос отправить не могу). Приведу строки.

34-ая строка, код вот такой с кометами:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) //есть ли переменная с логином в COOKIE.
```

Должна быть, если пользователь при предыдущем входе нажал на чекбокс "Запомнить".
Это уже сам оператор if

```
{
    //если да, то вставляем в форму ее значение. При этом  пользователю отображается, что его логин уже вписан в нужную графу
    echo    ' value="'.$_COOKIE['login'].'">';
}
```

Далее идет код и строка 84, в которой допущена ошибка.

```
  Вы вошли на сайт, как $_SESSION[login] (<a    href ='exit.php'>выход</a>)<br>
```

89-ая строчка с ошибкой

```
<img    alt='$_SESSION[login]' src='$myrow[avatar]'>
```

90-ая строчка с ошибкой

```
<-- Выше отображается аватар. Его адрес содержит переменная $myrow[avatar] -->
```

После знака < стоит знак !

Comment: @LordyGL Для добавления кода, надо выделить его мышью и нажать на кнопку 101010 или просто добавить по четыре пробела перед каждой строкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SESSION[login]`? вы копировали или сейчас в ручную писали.

Должно быть `$_SESSION['login']`

```
$myrow[avatar] --> $myrow['avatar']
```

А вообще мы не экстросенсы, приведите цитаты ошибок, скопируйте строки как положено(вставляя их в тег code)

---

статью вашу какой-то иди%;?№"т писал.

Вся проблема в

```
print <<<HERE
бла бла бла
HERE;
```

запомните две вещи по этому поводу

**1.** после

```
print <<<HERE
```

(!) на той же строке НИЧЕГО быть не должно, никаких знаков, цифр, букв, (!) пробелов! только переход на новую строку.

**2.** закрывающий тэг `HERE;` ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО должен начинаться с самого начала строки. так же после него ничего быть не должно! только переход на новую строку.

Comment: да долго получается 1 вопрос писать) А плс если не трудно скажите где можно выучить php? Там еще 34 строка)

Comment: Понятия не имею, все какие то книги советуют.

Я учился методом научного тыка. Могу посоветовать только php.su/net

Comment: Помоги с этим оператором плс)
<code>   
if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) 
        {
        echo    ' value="'.$_COOKIE['login'].'">';
        }          
</code>

Comment: тут все ок, просто следуйте тем двум указаниям что я дал выше про эти (print <<HERE)

Comment: Все спс большое! Только проблема была с этими HERE! Все остальное было не нужно.)))

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте вот это[link text](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)